# Cannot install Ubuntu 18.10 onto HP Compaq dc5800 via USB

Tags: nvidia, usb, windows

I got ubuntu on a usb and used etcher to flash it then I popped it in and booted it, and
[this is what my monitor shows when i turn on my pc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omKOT.jpg)

I have a "core 2 duo e8400" a "gt 710" and "4 gigs of ram"

ps: I don't really know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm guys, just had to update my BIOS. :P

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply that really helped!